# SVN Notifier Software

Tags: svn, notifications

What software can be used to get real time notifications when others commit changes to SVN or Source Control?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On Windows I use [CommitMonitor](https://tools.stefankueng.com/CommitMonitor.html) and like it a lot.

Answer (score 3):

I've also used [SVN Notifier](http://svnnotifier.tigris.org/) (for Windows) in the past and can recommend it - nice and lightweight.

Answer (score 2):

Using svn, your best bet would be a post-commit hook.  These are simple bash scripts that are ran after a commit is made.

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch05s02.html

Answer (score 1):

[websvn](http://www.websvn.info/) comes with *'rss feed support'*.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a hosted SVN system like Beanstalk, you could subscribe to the RSS feed and then use your RSS notifier of choice. On Mac, software like [NetNewsWire](http://netnewswireapp.com/) and [RSS Growler](http://osiris.laya.com/projects/RSSGrowler/) (which sadly seems to not work currently) can notify you via [Growl](http://growl.info).

Answer (score 0):

For linux
https://github.com/joaoneto

Answer (score 0):

There is android svn notifier too https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lilkillaware.svncheckes

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [SVN Notifier](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/svn-notifier/id574222085) menu bar app for Mac.